# Getting "Server not found " Error after upgrading ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: driver, upgrade, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, screen-resolution

I am new to linux/ubuntu and am trying to upgrade the ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS. I tried upgrading from terminal as well as from GUI. I used following command:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d 

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                                                                                 
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,342 kB]                                                                                                          
Fetched 1,343 kB in 6s (84.2 kB/s)                                                                                                     
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

I tried the following things:

1. select top 4 boxes on Tab1: Ubuntu Software from software & updates 2. Select top 2 boxes on Tab3: Updates from software & updates.
2. Try update and upgrade
3. No Success

Comment: I tried following things:
1. select top 4 boxes on Tab1: Ubuntu Software from software & updates
2. Select top 2 boxes on Tab3: Updates from software & updates.
3. Try update and upgrade 
4. No Success

Comment: 1. add contents on /etc/apt/sources.list 
2.sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 3. reboot
4. do-release-upgrade OP=> Authentication Error
Sol=> sudo sed -i 's/bionic/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
for Change bionic in /etc/apt/sources.list file to Focal.
Check cat /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo aBut now I am unable to use internet. Got Server not found error.
1. Tried adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 on /etc/resolv.conf => Not worked
2. Check ufw status => inactive.
content of /etc/resolv.conf
#Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver *.*.*.*

Comment: sudo resolvectl dns
Global : ****
Link 6(wlo1):
link 5(enp1s0f3) 
pt-get upgrade
ubuntu is upgraded to 20.04.5

Comment: I can see from your profile that you have not taken the [tour]. I suggest you take it now, as it will let you what this site is for (programming problems) and not for (server admin work, like upgrading Ubuntu)